# Current landmarks are not helpful for screen readers

Tags: feature-request, accessibility

The current markup on Stack Overflow is not very helpful for screen readers using landmarks to navigate the page. There are currently 19 different navigation items, only two of which have a label. There is also no `main` section.

According to the W3C, Stack Overflow is going against three of their guidelines:

- > [If a specific landmark role is used more than once on a web page, it should have a unique label](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/index.html#general_principles_1)
- > [Each page should have one main landmark](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/main.html)
- > [Avoid using the landmark role as part of the label](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/landmarks/index.html#general_principles_1)

This is what I see when I bring up landmark navigation on NVDA:

[image]

The current landmarks look something like this:

```
banner:
  - site navigation navigation
  - search
  - navigation
ask new question navigation:
content info:
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
  - navigation
```

I would recommend something more like this:

```
banner:
  - site navigation           # Remove 'navigation' from the label
  - search
  - secondary navigation      # Add a label to the secondary nav
main:                         # Add a main landmark
  - ask new question form     # Change the landmark from 'navigation' to 'form'
content info:
  - Stack overflow navigation # Add a label to each section
  - Stack overflow business navigation
  - Company navigation
  - Stack exchange network navigation
  # Remove all of the other nav elements from this list (you could probably add a few others but this is too long)
```

Comment: Pretty sure I've heard about the site getting a whole accessibility rework anyways?

Comment: @LW001 well then this is the exact time to make these kind of valuable suggestions, get the info in when it can really make a difference.